# xmlHttp.responseText does not return data from json webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to retrieve data from json webservice.

```
if (xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 0)
        {
            var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
            json = eval("(" + result + ")");
        }
```

i"m getting nothing for the var result. When i replace the webservice with a text file which contains json object, then i can retrieve the json object as responseText. Please help

Comment: Did you check what's the value of `xmlHttp.status`?

Comment: That code doesn't work, please post a working example.

Comment: value of xmlHttp.status is 0

Comment: Is the service on the same server as the service you're trying to call?  If not, you may be running afoul the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  If that's the case, you need to either proxy the service on your own site, or see if the service offers a JSONP version.

Comment: currently im running this service in localhost,its in the same server, i can see the json data when i run this service in the browser.

Comment: thanks scott, you are correct,i solve the problem by putting the app and webservice in to same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first... **never ever, ever, ever use `eval`***. `eval` = evil.

How to use `GET` with AJAX...

```
try {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e1) {
    try {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) {
        this.xmlhttp = null;
    }
}
var url = "/uri/of/web-service?val1=Laura&val2=Linney" + Math.random();
var params = "val1=Laura&val2=Linney";
http.open("GET", url, true);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        // we have a response and this is where we do something with it
        json = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send();
```

How to use `POST` with AJAX...

```
try {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e1) {
    try {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) {
        this.xmlhttp = null;
    }
}
var url = "/uri/of/web-service";
var params = "val1=Laura&val2=Linney";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        // we have a response and this is where we do something with it
        json = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: im trying to open the connection with GET, so may i know how this code change if it is a GET request?

Comment: Okay, shit, I must admit I've been using eval() over JSON.parse. You clearly say this is bad, so I only assume you know exactly why.. Would you mind educating me about this function and its risks? I'm assuming it'd be because eval() will execute any javascript functionality, whereas parse, will simply attempt to parse it into an object

Comment: @Atticus: If you own the service, `eval` is not quite so evil.  But `JSON.parse` is almost always better.  But note that it's not available on certain older browser, such as IE<8.  So you will either have to shim it or have a fallback and a check before using it.

Comment: i tried this code but im getting "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data" near the json=JSON.parse(http.responseText). may i know the reason?

Comment: @Atticus `eval` is evil where user-entered data, or data coming from elsewhere is concerned. It allows an attacker to run arbitrary code in your application.

Comment: @ishk 'unexpected end of data' usually occurs when you try to parse JSON twice. Hmmm... perhaps the data returned isn't JSON at all?

Comment: yes when i check the firebug console, it doesn't load the webservice. but when i open the webservice in the browser, i can see the well formatted json webservice. i also opened the webservice using chrome advanced rest client and i can see the json object.i cant figure out why its not loading when app is running

Comment: That sounds like you're running into the Same Origin Policy. Are you specifying the server as `localhost` or its IP?

Comment: i have depolyed the app in wamp server and run the webservice in seperate tomcat server which runs under ecilpse. i put the app in the tomcat server and now its working.thanks guys for giving me hints to solve this.

Comment: @ishk You should mark the best answer if there is one. No pressure. :)